# Couldn't get the date from DateField as expected in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, datefield

I tried to get value from datefield using `Ext.getCmp('dateFieldId')`. I expect it to be a string like 'dd-mm-yyyy'. But what I get is "Mon Feb 6 00:00:00 UTC......"

My code is

```
var effectivefromdate = new Ext.form.DateField({
    fieldLabel: 'XX',
    id:'XX',
    name: 'XX',
    format:'d/m/Y'
});
```

Plz help me on this,
I'm Stuck:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you get from `DateField` component is a `Date` object. To get a string from it use `Ext.Date.format(yourDateObject,'d-m-Y')`

Comment: For extjs3 please use `Ext.util.Format.date(yourDateObject, 'Y-m-d')`.

Comment: @Andron: I believe you mean ExtJS 4 where core `Date` prototype is no longer altered by utility functions. Although yes, you can use `Ext.util.Format.date` in ExtJS 3 too

Comment: @Mchl - in ExtJs 3.x (even in latest 3.4) it is possible to use only `Ext.util.Format.date`, e.g. you can play: [example](http://jsbin.com/edaciv/1/edit)

Comment: @Mchl - yes, you are right. But `Ext.Date.format(...)` will not work on ExtJs 3.4. This is what I want to say :)

Comment: @Andron: Yes it will and it does work. I use it everyday in my job. It's been removed in ExtJS 4, but is present in all ExtJS 3 versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it..

Ext.getCmp('your date id').getSubmitValue()